# Spring XD on YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spring-xd

I am getting the below error, while I am trying to install Spring XD on YARN.

```
Error executing a spring application; nested exception is org.springframework.yarn.YarnSystemException: 
Call From c01dfobi43.vcac.dc1.dsghost.net/100.98.226.45 to c01dfobi41.vcac.dc1.dsghost.net:8032 failed on connection exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused; 
nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: 
Call From c01dfobi43.vcac.dc1.dsghost.net/100.98.226.45 to c01dfobi41.vcac.dc1.dsghost.net:8032 failed on connection exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Not sure where I am committing a mistake. Also do we need to install Spring XD Yarn on all nodes?
It would be great if you can share any documentation mentioned explicitly for YARN.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here - http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#running-on-YARN

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for responding. I am seeing my applications getting run on YARN however when i am asking for admininfo its not returning admin details. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that c01dfobi41.vcac.dc1.dsghost.net:8032 is a ResourceManager host, I am also going to assume that based on your comment stating that yarn applications do run, you have more then one.  In that case what may be happening (and I see this all the time) is that your yarn client attempts to contact the resource manager by looking it up in yarn-site.xml, it picks the first one and gets ConnectionRefused as the standby resource manager does not listen on its RPC port, it moves on to the next one and succeeds.  If this is the case this is not a fatal error and can be ignored.